# Is there a way to view a list of all Telegram groups or channels which didn't belong to any folder?

Tags: telegram, telegram-bot

I want to view a list of all Telegram groups or channels which didn't belong to or weren't included in any folder that I've created before. Can anyone help me? Thanks in advance!